# array of structure pointers error in graph program

Tags: c, pointers, graph, struct

I am trying to make a graph this program is just in initial phases where I 
 declared an array of structure pointers which holds address of vertices
 *vertices[20] is an array which whose elements are all addresses of type  **struct node *** which will contain the address of node of graphs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *links[10];
};
struct node *create_node(int);
void create_vertices(struct node **);
int main()
{
    struct node *vertices[20];
    int d, i, choice;
        *vertices[0]=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)*20);
        create_vertices (&vertices);
}

struct node *create_node(int data)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        temp->links[i] = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void create_vertices (struct node **v)
{
 int i,choice;
 i=0;
    printf("enter choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice == 1) {
        printf("enter data\n");
        scanf("%d", &d);
        vertices[i] = create_node(d);
        i++;
        printf("enter choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
}
```

Compiling the above code gives me following errors

```
bfs.c: In function ‘main’:
bfs.c:13:21: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct node’ from type ‘struct node *’
bfs.c:14:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create_vertices’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
bfs.c:8:6: note: expected ‘struct node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct node * (*)[20]’
bfs.c: In function ‘create_vertices’:
bfs.c:35:16: error: ‘d’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bfs.c:35:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
bfs.c:36:3: error: ‘vertices’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

the program says an error in following line

```
    struct node *vertices[20];
*vertices[0]=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)*20);
```

what is the harm in this kind of declaration.
I declare an array of pointers of type struct node * should I give memory also to them.

Comment: Drop the asterix in the lvalue. The type should be a pointer, not a node. vertices[0] **is** a pointer. Also remove the casts.

Comment: @wildplasser I have a confusion here how will vertices[1] be stored because if I give all the memory to vertices[0] what I am trying to do is create an array vertices[0],vertices[1],vertices[2],vertices[3] and so on I am trying to use malloc for the same

Comment: You can remove the entire malloc() line. Vertices[] is an array of 20 pointers. The create_vertices() function will give the pointers a value (by calling malloc() plus a couple of assignments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main:

```
create_vertices (&vertices);
```

should be:

```
create_vertices (vertices);
```

Also: it would be more safe to let the create_vertices() function know what the size of the array is. The i index should not be allowed to exceed this size.

UPDATE: in main, **remove** the line:

```
*vertices[0]=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)*20);
```

Vertices[] is an array of 20 (uninitialised) pointers in automatic storage ("on the stack").

The create_vertices() function will give the pointers a value. (by calling malloc() and assigning the result to vertices[i])